# Is it possible make radial gauge in the given image format in ssrs 2012?

Tags: reporting-services

I want a radial gauge in ssrs 2012 like below mentioned image format.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207041.aspx) and [this](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s145/creating-ssrs-gauges.htm), to get a similar presentation to your image you have to play with the gauge properties.

Comment: @Zuleta.. Okay i ll check

Comment: I didn't get that default colors... Need to write any expression for that in scale properties?